# What is the Eurofighter's altitude record?

Tags: aircraft-performance, eurofighter-typhoon, zoom-climb

The Eurofighter Typhoon is a pretty nimble fighter jet, and many European countries use it in their military. Its service ceiling is 65,000 ft, but what is its current altitude record from a zoom climb (i.e. apogee record)? How high can a Eurofighter get in a zoom climb, assuming ideal weather and maximum lightness by having little fuel left and no missiles on it? Would you be able to reach an apogee above 95,300 ft (29 km) in a zoom climb?

Also, what is the ideal altitude for a Eurofighter to start a zoom climb from, to get as high as possible? Answers/comments based on personal experiences are welcome as well.